# BASH script - Unzip and remove gz files directly

Tags: bash, gzip, gunzip

I need to perform two decompression: tar and then the inner gz's.
Following the piece of code I'm using in my bash script:

```
for filename in $path; do
    tar -xf $filename -C $untar/$num


    for nc_gz in `ls "$untar"/"$num"/*`; do
          gunzip $nc_gz

    done

    for nc in `ls "$untar"/"$num"/*`; do
          ...
    done
done
```

It works as expected: each tar contains N gz archives, which are unzipped and deleted, keeping also the inner uncompressed files.

But, I'd like to uncompress each gz one a time, in order to save disk space.

I tried this:

```
for filename in $path; do
    tar -xf $filename -C $untar/$num
done    

for nc_gz in `ls "$untar"/"$num"/*`; do
    STEM=$(basename "${nc_gz}" .gz)
    gunzip -c $nc_gz > $untar/$num/$STEM

    nc="$untar"/"$num"/$STEM
    .....
    rm $nc
done
```

but the gunzip operation also keeps the gz file.

How could I edit my code in order to achieve the goal?

Thanks

Comment: You would do better to use ```for nc_gz in "$untar"/"$num"/*; do``` without using the backticks or `$(…)` for command substitution.  And you should use double quotes around `$STEM`, too. That is, however, tangential to your question.

Comment: Your goal is not really clear.  A plain `gunzip "$nc_gz"` would remove the `.gz` file and unpack the contents into the a file with the right name.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've just tested the second code block with no -c option and it works as I want.

Comment: Do you want to delete the question, or would you prefer a write up as an answer?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You can answer my question if you want, so I can vote it as the best one. It was a spark to test my code